# Trying to make a Roblox group payout API; doesn't pay out or give output

Tags: php

I am working on a Roblox group payout API, and if it works I am planning to set it open for public

Problem: It shows output `{}`, but it doesn't payout anything

Before I could start working on this, I first needed to create a manual payout where I got all the POST parameters and headers. Here is what I got:

```html
METHOD: POST
URL: https://web.roblox.com/groups/3182156/one-time-payout/false
REQUEST BODY: percentages=%7B%22457792390%22:%221%22%7D

HEADERS:
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
referer: https://web.roblox.com/my/groupadmin.aspx?gid=3182156&_=1528631875891
cookie: GuestData=UserID=-608861174; RBXMarketing=FirstHomePageVisit=1; RBXSource=rbx_acquisition_time=6/9/2018 6:18:42 AM&rbx_acquisition_referrer=https://v3rmillion.net/showthread.php?tid=583440&rbx_medium=Direct&rbx_source=v3rmillion.net&rbx_campaign=&rbx_adgroup=&rbx_keyword=&rbx_matchtype=&rbx_send_info=1; rbx-ip=; __utmc=200924205; __utmz=200924205.1528621282.6.4.utmcsr=robuxrewards.site|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; __utma=200924205.428322191.1519910430.1528621282.1528630905.7; RBXImageCache=timg=63313634633937632D393938342D346262642D613663612D333133653130363363373938253231372E3130332E32392E32303925362F31302F323031382031313A34333A303220414D3E2434B19B5881BB5B51486D88F43FC8F5D5787F; __utmt_b=1; gig_hasGmid=ver2; .ROBLOSECURITY=HERE_WAS_A_COOKIE; RBXEventTrackerV2=CreateDate=6/10/2018 6:52:37 AM&rbxid=455629576&browserid=15138233029; __RequestVerificationToken=w6L7tvgTk0c8TeMvuz8QnvVEoF7W7mMxk6UcefoCygoXk97mWkqQGKiLD6XLz5Bssx9FTqkFCzvclhqdrVyww9VcrNY1; RBXSessionTracker=sessionid=a45dce07-ff59-4590-8881-b4200425cf02; __utmb=200924205.11.10.1528630905
```

I deleted the `.ROBLOSECURITY` because with that you can login into my account. But that is all the info I got. With the request body: `percentages=%7B%22457792390%22:%221%22%7D`, When I decode that, I get this: `percentages={"457792390":"1"}` That is good, because my user id is `457792390` and the amount I payed out is `1`. So I created a code that should make this work, and make it automatic. Here it is:

```html
<?php

// Receive
$module = $_GET['module'];
$cookie = $_GET['cookie'];
$amount = $_GET['amount'];
$group_id = $_GET['group_id'];
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
/* https://freewebhost.fun/api.php?module=group_payout&cookie=YOUR_COOKIE_HERE&amount=YOUR_AMOUNT_HERE&group_id=YOUR_GROUP_ID_HERE&user_id=USERNAME_HERE */

// The function
function group_payout($cookie, $amount, $group_id, $user_id) {
    // preset stuff
    $content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    
    // further
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://web.roblox.com/groups/".$group_id."/one-time-payout/false");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "percentages=%7B%22" . $user_id . "%22:%22" . $amount . "%22%7D");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: ".$content_type, "Cookie: .ROBLOSECURITY=".$cookie."; RBXViralAsquisition=time=1/24/2018 11:50:50 AM&referrer=https://www.google.nl/&originatingsite=www.google.nl&viraltarget=945929481; RBXSource=rbx_acquisition_time=6/11/2018 1:47:00 AM&rbx_acquisition_referrer=&rbx_medium=Direct&rbx_source=&rbx_campaign=&rbx_adgroup=&rbx_keyword=&rbx_matchtype=&rbx_send_info=1; __utzm=200924205.1516985949.4.3.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); "));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://web.roblox.com/my/groupadmin.aspx?gid='.$group_id.'#nav-payouts');
    
    
    
    // Lets go
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $server_output;
    
}

if ($module == "group_payout") {
    group_payout($cookie, $amount, $group_id, $user_id);
}

?>
```

I really don't know what the problem can be.

### Edit

So, in the comments somebody told me to try out PostMan. Here are the results:
https://pastebin.com/raw/iN4UQPBE (it's too big for the character limit here).

I don't know what to do with these results.

Comment: Have you tried `<?php` instead of `</php>`?

Comment: Ah thanks! I didn't see that. But it still doesn't payout. It gives output tho. The output it gives is `{}`

Comment: @Justinas I forgot to mention you

Comment: have you tested the request from PostMan or any other tool to verify wheather the endpoint is responding properly for data mentioned.

Comment: @AtulSharma I dont know how to use PostMan

Comment: @AtulSharma I have coded this on my chromebook, And I can only use my chromebook at the moment. So PostMan won't be a choise.

Comment: @AtulSharma I added postman results. i don't really know what to do with them.

Comment: This looks a bit risky - you're injecting URL components from user input without any validation at all. When you're grabbing values from `$_GET` it is worth ensuring they look OK before injecting them into an API call, in case they do something dodgy.

Comment: That's still a bit from a [mcve]. If HTTP parameter passing is the problem, reduce your code to that. If the processing is, you could eliminate the whole HTTP stuff from your question and just provide a simple PHP script that can be started from the commandline. Further, if the HTTP request from your script to roblox.com is the issue, you should be able to eliminate the whole PHP part and rather use cURL or wget from the commandline.

Answer (score 1):

Your XSRF token is invalid. You should include it in the request headers.

To get your XSRF token, send a POST request to https://api.roblox.com/sign-out/v1 with your cookie in the headers. The XSRF token should be in the response headers.